# R not allowing to write documents, Error in cpp_pdf_select(input, output, pages, password)

Tags: r, pdftools

I'm trying to use the following code, which is supossed to order the pages of a pdf:

```
ordenar <- function(archivo) {
  
  library(pdftools)
  
  nombre <- sapply(strsplit(sapply(strsplit(pdftools::pdf_text(archivo), 
                                            "Nombre: +"), `[`, 2), "\r"), `[`, 1)
  nombre <- as.character(nombre)
  
  OBRA <- sapply(strsplit(sapply(strsplit(pdftools::pdf_text(archivo),"Depto\\.: +"), `[`, 2), "\r"), `[`, 1)
  
  OBRA <- as.character(OBRA)
  
  OBRA <- substr(OBRA,1,5)
  
  OBRA <- as.data.frame(OBRA)
  
  combine_n <- cbind(OBRA,nombre)
  
  pagina <- time(nombre)
  
  combine_n <- cbind(combine_n,pagina)
  
  orden<- with(combine_n, combine_n[order(OBRA, nombre) , ])
 
  ordenado <- as.vector(orden$pagina)
  
  pdf_subset(archivo, pages = ordenado, output = "compilado_a-z.pdf")
}
```

The code works fine on other computers but in the one I'm currently at I get this error:

```
Error in cpp_pdf_select(input, output, pages, password) : 
  open C:\Users\HP\Documents\prueba\compilado_a-z.pdf: Permission denied
```

I have ran parts of the code and it is able to extract data from the pdf, the problem occurs when it tries to create a new pdf, I have also tried to export a dataframe to excel and I get the same error. This is a work computer, should I call IT or is it an internal problem?

Comment: Does the "C:\Users\HP\Documents\prueba\" path already exist? Since the error says "Permission denied" it's something you should ask your IT team about. Find a directory you have permissions to write to.